# Whats the person called who updates war maps

Tags: single-word-requests

If you picture in any war movie, you'll have three or four people standing around moving components on a war map. What are those people called? **Cartographers, Mapmakers, or Map operators?**

> “And where is that Blood ridge you mentioned?” Seamus asked.  “There,”
> the monk said pointing a chubby finger at a spot on the map 100 yards
> behind Boru's encampment.  “Lugaid, I think we found our new
> **mapmaker**.”

---

Cartographers?
Mapmakers?
Map operators?

Comment: Related, whose title or answers might or might not switch on the light bulb: [A verb for “The cartographer painstakingly ___ a map of the city.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424779/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In British English at least, this job role would have been a 'plotter', as someone who plotted the position of objects on the map.

Comment: Thank you, I would not have come up with that without you. Much appreciated.